# Problems with debugging Shiny in R version 4

Tags: r, debugging, shiny

I just recently upgraded to R version 4.0.3 and using this version, I can no longer debug my Shiny apps, either using browser() or by setting a breakpoint. Including either of these in the script leads to Rstudio crashing as soon as I click on 'run app'. If I switch back to an earlier version of R, everything runs smoothly, but due to some other packages that I use, I would like to use R version 4.

Any ideas how I can get browser() working in R version 4 within Shiny?
I have included below an example app from Shiny to illustrate the problem with browser(). When this is commented out in R version 4, the app works fine.
I found a similar post using an older version of R here [RStudio Shiny app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841517/rstudio-shiny-app-crashes)
that suggested that the packages needed to be updated. When I included the update.packages line in the script below, Rstudio still crashed, when it got to running the app.

```
library(shiny)
#update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   browser() 
    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Just as a data point: for me the debugging works with `R 4.0.2`, `shiny 1.5.0` and `RStudio 1.3.1056`